# Switching Values with chrome storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I want to save a boolean value by clicking on a picture that changes its state from true to false every time I click onto the picture.

So simply I want to write something like

```
function SwitchByImage(propertyName) {
   var oldValue=chrome.storage.sync.get({propertyName}, null);
   var newValue=!oldValue;
   chrome.storage.sync.set({propertyName:newValue},null);
   if (newValue) { 
      $("#whateverimage").attr("src","upimage.jpg");
   } else {
      $("#whateverimage").attr("src","downimage.jpg");
   }
}
```

I *know* that this does not work. Where I added "null" should be a function. My problem is: The storage works asynchronous, so it does not seem to be possible to write and read my data in a sequence.

What is the best way to get around this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since **[`chrome.storage.sync.get`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html#method-StorageArea-get)** is asynchronous, the fetched value will be available in the callback, so that is where the rest of the code should be placed:

```
function SwitchByImage(propertyName) {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(propertyName, function(items) {
        var oldValue = items[propertyName];
        var newValue = !oldValue;
        chrome.storage.sync.set({ propertyName: newValue });
        if (newValue) { 
            $("#whateverimage").attr("src", "upimage.jpg");
        } else {
           $("#whateverimage").attr("src","downimage.jpg");
        }
    });
}
```